# Chrome issue overriding inline styles when printing

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, inline

I have an inline style that has to be applied via javascript which i need to remove when printing. I've applied div[style] with !important to override, this works perfectly in the other browsers i've tested but it doesn't work in Chrome (Version 40.0.2214.91). Has anyone had this issue before or come across a solution?

Inline style

```
<div class="main" style="margin-top: 627px;">
 ....
</div>
```

Print CSS

```
@media print {
  .main[style] {
      margin-top: 0!important;
   }
}
```

Comment: can you post some code , it will be more helpful to figure out issue

Comment: Sure, i've added in the code, there is no margin top applied in my normal styles, it is only applied inline on the tag. Is this enough?

Comment: print css applies,working ok in my chrome browser    'Version 39.0.2171.95 dev-m'   , in which version you are trying?

Comment: It'sVersion 40.0.2214.91

Comment: @Sephorra 
  .main[style] {
      margin-top: 0!important;
   -webkit-margin-before: 0px !important;}

Comment: @Sephorra give 0px to your margin-top if before is not working

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately neither worked. Im thinking i might need to write some JS to just rip the style out when printing. What a pain!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Chrome version 44.0.2403.125 m.

In my case, it was accordion-like functionality that relied on JS setting inline negative margins on an element. I wanted to show the previously hidden content automatically on print.

While not *technically* a good solution to the problem, setting `display:inline;` worked, since inline does not allow any margins.